# format row(s) based on filter condition in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that contains rows in sorted order based on a date column. Now I want to highlight the row(make it bold) which is nearest to the current date but not greater than it, i.e., today>=max (dates where date <= current date). Can someone please help me out on how to achieve this?

--Update--

I have solved the problem by moving the expression to another cell and then referencing the cell in the conditional formatting from there. Now I have a new problem, I want to generate one cell's value and make that non-editable. In simple words, I want to generate create date of a row and put that date in a column named create date. I think I have to use the google apps script but not sure if the idea of putting a system-generated date in a column is feasible.

Comment: Hi, do you have a code you're working on? Consider explaining what you tried so far, and what specific issues you came across.

Comment: I tried with this =$F1=(MAX(FILTER(F: F, F: F<=today()))) where F contains the date values and my sheet data ranges from column A to I. This I have put inside conditional formatting but the issue is only that column A of the selected row is formatted, not the whole column.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? Do you want to use `google-apps-script` for this?

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: How can I share my spreadsheet for anonymous access without a security risk of public access? Google app script should be fine. I just need a solution, because I have no idea what is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, since you found a solution, consider posting an answer explaining it, and post a new question to tackle your new problem.